# Junit through terminal

Tags: java, junit, junit4, hamcrest

I have a folder containing junit.jar,hamcrest-core-1.3.jar, and my java files containing the tests. I am running "javac -cp ./junit.jar: Tests.java" to compile my junit test. When I go to run my test with "java -cp ./junit.jar:. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Tests" I get the following error "UnitCore Tests
JUnit version 4.11
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing"

Any help??

Comment: Looks like some of your test classes requires this external jar. Add the jar that contains `org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing` class as part of your classpath.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, mind providing me with an exmaple? I currently have one Test java file (Tests.java).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14539072/1065197

Comment: "javac -cp ./junit.jar:hamcrest-core.jar Tests.java" or "java -cp ./junit.jar:hamcrest-core.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Tests"

Comment: got it. second option. thanks!