# How to check if I set CLASSPATH correctly? (Junit error)

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, classpath

I installed Junit and tried to follow one of to tutorial videos on YouTube. I added junit-4.11 to my CLASSPATH correctly but when I run my Junit test, I get initializationError. echo %CLASSPATH% shows the junit-4.11.jar correctly. What could be causing this?

```
package test;

public class Junit {

public String concatenate(String one, String two)
{
    return one + two;
}

public int multiply(int number1, int number2)
{
    return number1 * number2;
}
}


package test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
public class MultiplyTest {

@Test
public void testMultiply() {
    Junit test = new Junit();
    int result = test.multiply(3,4);
    assertEquals(12, result);
}
}





java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 25 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539072/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-hamcrest-selfdescribing)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add hamcrest-all.jar to your classpath also. This question is answered here: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539072/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-hamcrest-selfdescribing)

Comment: Thank you! It is listed in the download page of junit, I can't believe I missed it..