# Creating Junit Test Case - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, junit

I am new to Junit, and I am having issues creating a Junit Test Case. It is causing the error java.lang.NoClassDefFound, as well as a lot of other errors.

I have the following code in a class called Arithmetic:

```
 public class Arithmetic {
  public static int addition(number, number2) { 
        return number + number2;
  }
```

The Junit test code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;


public class TestFailure {

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
Arithmetic test = new Arithmetic();
int output = test.addition(5,8);
assertEquals(13, output);
}

}
```

This returns the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass                      (JUnit4Builder.java:10)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 25 more
```

Note that I have downloaded the junit-4.12.jar and have it installed where my projects are. It is also in my Referenced Libraries as junit-4.12.jar, with a drop down list of many more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539072/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-hamcrest-selfdescribing)

Answer (score 1):

JUnit is depending on [Hamcrest](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core), add that to the path as well.

Answer (score 0):

Added **hamcrest-all-1.3.jar** to class path.

[hamcrest jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all/1.3)

Answer (score 0):

You need a Hamcrest. See JUnit's [Getting started](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Getting-started) article.