# NoClassDefFoundError (initialization error) when i use JUNIT to test a class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Like the title says, i get an initialization error when i try running a test using Junit. Junit tests other example unit tests without problems so i don't think Junit.jar itself is to blame, i can't see the problem in my own self made test class either. Here is the stacktrace information:

> org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
>     at >java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

its a program that basically tests whether a specific data row is retrieved correctly from a mySQL database. So the tested class connects to a database on my computer and tries to retrieve data from it.

can anyone help please?

Kind regards,

Comment: Most of these errors are duet to classpath issues. Make sure your class/jar is in classpath.

Comment: You are missing the hamcrest-core jar file from classpath.

Comment: Add stacktrace and test class with import section.

Comment: I believe you have the suficient answer in [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539072/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-hamcrest-selfdescribing).