# JUnit - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing

Tags: junit, junit4, hamcrest

I am using Win 7 and downloaded Junit 4.13 and hamcrest 2.1 from 
https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Download-and-Install

and put them in a folder named JUnit under C.

I have added the variable: JUNIT_HOME with value C:\JUnit.

I have also added the following to my classpath:

```
%classpath%;.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin;%CLASSPATH%; 
%JUNIT_HOME%\junit-4.13-beta-1;.; %JUNIT_HOME%\hamcrest-core-2.1.jar;
```

Following https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Getting-started,
I added the java files Calculator.java and CalculatorTest.java to my practice folder.

The command

```
javac -cp .;junit-4.13-beta-1.jar;hamcrest-core-2.1.jar CalculatorTest.java
```

is executed successfully. However, the command

```
java -cp .;junit-4.13-beta-1.jar;hamcrest-core-2.1.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore CalculatorTest
```

Fails, giving an error message like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:28)
    at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:77)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.createRequest(JUnitComma
ndLineParseResult.java:116)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:77)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
```

Please note I have checked posts like [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539072/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-hamcrest-selfdescribing), but they have not been helpful. Could you please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct hamcrest jar is `hamcrest-2.1.jar`, not `hamcrest-core-2.1.jar`. You can download it from [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.hamcrest).

---

According to mentioned [guide](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Getting-started) it is assumed you have downloaded jars in the same package as your project:

> Create a new folder junit-example and download the current
>   junit-4.XX.jar from JUnit's release page and Hamcrest to this folder.

If you decided to put jars separately probably you need to correct the command line correspondingly to take these jars files from `%JUNIT_HOME%`:

```
java -cp .;%JUNIT_HOME%\junit-4.13-beta-1.jar;%JUNIT_HOME%\hamcrest-core-2.1.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore CalculatorTest
```

Comment: Thanks. I copied the jar files from C:\JUnit to my practice folder C:\Prac, and ran the command you suggested. It still gives me errors. I was assuming since I have set the classpath then I don't have to include the jar folders under C:\Prac. But anyways it still gives errors.

Comment: Today I had more time and played with it locally. I was able to reproduce it and found the root cause of issue - wrong hamcrest jar. I have updated my post above.