# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing despite having hamcrest on classpath

Tags: java, ant, junit5, hamcrest

When attempting to run tests with JUnit 5 via the Ant `junitlauncher` task, I receive the following message:

> [junitlauncher] WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to execute tests
>   [junitlauncher] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing

How do I fix this so that my tests can run?

The answers to similar questions (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539072/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-hamcrest-selfdescribing)) mainly say to make sure that hamcrest is on the classpath. I've verified using the `print-test-classpath` target (see build file below for details) that the classpath I'm using to run my tests includes `hamcrest-2.1.jar`. Furthermore, the tests compile without any issue.

Here are the sections of my build.xml I think are relevant:

```xml
<path id="lib-only-class.path">
  <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
    <include name="**/*.jar" />
  </fileset>
</path>

<path id="class.path">
  <path refid="lib-only-class.path"/>
  <pathelement location="${classes.dir}"/>
</path>

<path id="test-class.path">
  <path refid="class.path"/>
  <pathelement location="${test-classes.dir}"/>
</path>

<target name="compile-tests" depends="compile">
  <mkdir dir="${test-classes.dir}"/>
  <javac srcdir="${test.dir}" destdir="${test-classes.dir}"
         includeantruntime="no" classpathref="class.path"/>
</target>

<target name="test" depends="compile-tests">
  <junitlauncher printsummary="yes">
    <classpath refid="test-class.path"/>
    <testclasses>
      <fileset dir="${test-classes.dir}"/>
    </testclasses>
  </junitlauncher>
</target>

<target name="print-test-classpath">
  <pathconvert property="classpathInName" refid="test-class.path"/> 
  <echo>Classpath is ${classpathInName}</echo>
</target>
```

Comment: Which JUnit version you are using?

Comment: JUnit Jupiter. Engine and API 5.5.1, platform 1.5.1

Comment: Did you check by downgrading the current version? Like to 5.3.2?