# i can not test my java code on visual studio using the java test runner extension

Tags: java, testing, visual-studio-code, junit

hi there I am trying to test my code java code with the JUnit test case
but there is a problem with the tester
 I don't know what it is, happy to get from your review and guides
check this image to see the test failed message>>
[image: test code with JUnit for java] 
ass you see in the I, age the test run failed
 I do not know why happy to gee reviews and if you can guide me to fix the issue and make it run properly

here also the full java test runner failed message>>

```
Message:
N/A
Stack trace:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:821)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:719)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:642)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:600)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: Are you using maven or gradle to setup your project? Can you make sure, that hamcrest is added to your classpath? 
Also, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539072/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-hamcrest-selfdescribing

Comment: I just have installed the junit.jar and hamcrest on my "referenced libraries"!
did I need to make any other things? @Lesrac

Comment: Can you post the code for me to reproduce the error if it's convenient?

Comment: `//import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.Test; 
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
//import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class Ex3Test {

    @Test
 void testsum() {
        assertEquals(Ex3.sum(4, 5),9);
    
    }}`
and the sum function on the Ex3.java return 4+5(which equals 9)

maybe I need to import a package on my Ex3test.java?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download [hamcrest-2.2.jar](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest/2.2/jar) and **[Add it to Referenced Libraries](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_add-a-jar)**;
   [image]
2. State the `class Ex3Test` and the method `testsum` as **Public**:
   [image]